# Минимизация AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Господа, на странице есть много разных форм с отправкой через AJAX

```
$('КАКАЯ-то ФОРМА').submit(function(){
        $.post('<?=Url::toRoute("КАКОЙ-то ЭКШН")?>', {
            'id_gift_reciever' : $('#id_gift_reciever').val(),
            'mem_date' : $('#mem_date').val(),
            //таких много разных 
        }, function() {

        })

        return false;
    });
```

Как бы написать такую штуку универсальную (где буду передаваться любые id input) не указывая поля явно

Comment: FormData. . . .

Answer (score 0):

> Как бы написать такую штуку универсальную (где буду передаваться любые id input) не указывая поля явно

Вот так, если в формах нет файлов:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Обарботает поля в зависимости от того на какую нажато
    let data = $(this).serializeArray();
    // Тут может идти ваш код для AJAX
    // ....
    console.log(data);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="form1">
  <input type="text" name="in1.1">
  <input type="text" name="in1.2">
  <select name="sel" id="">
    <option value="0">Default</option>
    <option value="1">You choose</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Send 1</button>
</form>
<form action="" class="form2">
  <input type="text" name="in2.1">
  <input type="text" name="in2.2">
  <button type="submit">Send 2</button>
</form>
```

---

**UPD:** Благодарю @andreymal

С обработкой файлов:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
});



/***
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form')

forms.forEach(function (form) { 
  form.addEventListener('submit',function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = new FormData(e.target);
    //console.log(e.target.classList[0]);
    //let file = document.querySelector('.' + e.target.classList[0] +' > input[type="file"]')
    //console.log(file.files);
    //data.append(file.getAttribute('name'), file.files[0])
    
     var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      body: data // Отправка самой формы
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((json) => { // Ответ
     
      // Дебаг узнать что прошла форма
      console.log(json)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  })
})
****/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="form1">
  <input type="text" name="in1.1">
  <input type="text" name="in1.2">
  <select name="sel" id="">
    <option value="0">Default</option>
    <option value="1">You choose</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Send 1</button>
</form>
<form action="" class="form2">
  <input type="text" name="in2.1">
  <input type="text" name="in2.2">
  <input type="file" name="myFile2">
  <button type="submit">Send 2</button>
</form>
```

---

- [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) - функция не требует явного указания полей, но надо в полях указывать атрубут `name` для коректной работы.
- [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) - позваляет создать ключ значение из формы для поледующей передачи по AJAX.

Comment: «Data from file select elements is not serialized», а жаль

Comment: Допустим, мне нужно сразу присваивать атрибут name тобиш в консоле должен быть массив in2.1="значение из инпута" in2.2="значение из инпута"